# Perl opening multiple files and importing into a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, perl, import

I'm looking to import over 600 txt files into MySQL, and was looking to use perl and the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.  In the sense that it connects, then disconnects, but doesn't seem to open each file and process as per instructions, so my import table remains empty.  The directory exists, so not sure what could be wrong unless there are obvious errors in my code. I get no error messages when I execute the perl script.  Each file has one reecord per line, with a \n character to denote the end of record.  I hope someone can help, this little problem is perplexing and I can't see any obvious reason as to why it would not work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# Set datasource
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:host=somehost;database=somedb"
        . ";port=someport";

# Connect to database 
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"someuser","somepassword");
print "Status: Connected to MySQL.\n";

my $dir = "t:\\some directory";

opendir (DIR, $dir) or die "Unable to open directory";
my @files = grep /\.txt/, readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

foreach my $file (@files) {
open(FH, '<', "$dir\\$file") or die "Unable to open $file - $!\n";
while (<FH>){ 
    my $data = split (/\n$/);
    my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO sometable 
            (TEXTDATA,SOURCEFILE) 
        VALUES (?,?)') or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr(); 
$insert->execute($data,$file) or die "Execute failed: " . $dbh->errstr(); 
}
close(FH);
}
print "Status: Processing of complete.\n";

# Disconnect from the database
$dbh->disconnect ();
print "Status: Disconnected from MySQL.";
```

Comment: Try writing a log entry for each file to check that you find all files. The `<FH>` operator already splits on newline, so you `split`operation is strange; did you mean `chomp`?

Comment: Before my while (<FH>) line I've put in  print "$file.\n"; to see what is the current file, but this doesn't print anything to the screen.  The split is something I've used in other code.  if I remove the split statement and replace with chomp, what would I replace my $data variable with in the $insert->execute($data,$file... statement

Comment: If I do a print "@files.\n", then it only returns a .  Does this mean the grep is not working as I would have thought the should be more than . in the @files

Comment: How can I get a clean list of just .txt files into my @files array.

Comment: If `print "@files.\n"`writes a `.` it doesn't mean that `@files` includede a `.` but that you put it there in the print statement. But I don't see any obvious problems with your code. Try print all the entries you get from `readdir`. Try using real slashes (i.e. `/`) instead of backslashes.

Comment: I can only guess, that `readdir` returns files with capitals and regexp in grep is case sensitive, so it won't match "TXT". Try remove grep temporary:

    my @files = readdir(DIR);
    print "@files\n";

Comment: How large are the files and how quickly does this code complete when you run it? Assuming the files add up to more than a few tens of megabytes, it should run for several seconds (or several minutes...) if it's actually reading the import files; if it exits instantly and the import files aren't very small, then it's failing to find the import files.

Comment: Re: kompas's suggestion, changing the grep to `grep /\.txt/i, ...` (note the added `i`) will make it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the things you're doing are a good deal out of date.

- Use forward slashes instead of backslashes for your path separator. Perl will do the right thing.
- Your prepare statement isn't doing much good if it is being prepared on each iteration. It should be prepared once outside of the loops.
- New lines are record separators by default. So, don't use split to store a line of data into a variable, just assign the line to the variable.
- You're not checking if you actually found any files in the given path either.

I've made the corrections as follows:

```
use v5.12;
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# Set datasource
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:host=somehost;database=somedb;port=someport";

# Connect to database 
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"someuser","somepassword")
    or die "Couldn't connect to MySQL server: $!";
say "Status: Connected to MySQL.";

my $source_dir = "t:/some/directory";

# Store the handle in a variable.
opendir my $dirh, $source_dir or die "Unable to open directory: $!";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $dirh;
closedir $dirh;

# Stop script if there aren't any files in the list
die "No files found in $source_dir" unless @files;

# You can comment out the following two lines
# once you're sure things are working
say 'Importing data from:';
say for @files;

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO sometable (TEXTDATA,SOURCEFILE) '
                           . 'VALUES (?,?)')
                           or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr(); 
for my $file (@files) {
    say "Processing $source_dir/$file";
    open my $fh, '<', "$source_dir/$file"
        or die "Unable to open $source_dir/$file: $!\n";

    # Don't use split. Just assign the line.
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
       $insert->execute($line,$file)
           or die "Execute failed: " . $dbh->errstr(); 
    }

    close $fh;
}
print "Status: Processing of complete.\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Will test on another set of files I have to import.  Do I still use the / character even if I'm running this on a Windows machine?  Also, is there a reason to use v5.12 when I'm using v5.14.

Comment: Yes, use the forward slash even on a Windows machine. It has never caused me any issues on my Windows scripts. If you have 5.14, then `use v5.14;` to get the latest features enabled.

Comment: Works perfectly - very nice

Comment: What goes in place of `TEXTDATA`? I'm assuming `SOURCEFILE` is just the name of the .txt file containing the tab-delimited data...

Comment: @user1854603: A line of text from the source file. Each line becomes it's own entry into the DB and is associated with the source file.